# How to grep files in date order

Tags: bash

I can list the Python files in a directory from most recently updated to least recently updated with

```
ls -lt *.py
```

But how can I grep those files in that order?

I understand one should never try to parse the output of `ls` as that is a very dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use this pipeline to achieve this with `gnu` utilities:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.py' -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
sort -z -t : -rnk1 |
cut -z -d : -f2- |
xargs -0 grep 'pattern'
```

This will handle filenames with special characters such as space, newline, glob etc.

1. `find` finds all `*.py` files in current directory and prints modification time (epoch value) + `:` + filename + `NUL` byte
2. `sort` command performs reverse numeric sort on first column that is timestamp
3. `cut` command removes 1st column (timestamp) from output
4. `xargs -0 grep` command searches `pattern` in each file

Comment: Thank you. This is far more complicated than I was expecting!

Comment: How about `eval "sorted=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-escape *.py))"; grep foo "${sorted[@]}"` ?

Comment: See the bottom of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . `--quoting-style=shell-escape` is the official way to avoid the parsing problem.

Comment: ok thanks but you will still need to write more code to be able to run `grep` on each of this filename

Comment: Yes. The grep is included in the one liner I pasted.

Comment: oh yes that's good. btw `--quoting-style=c` also works and is a bit shorter

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way if you want to get the filelist in chronologic order that hold the pattern:

```
grep -sil <searchpattern> <files-to-grep> | xargs ls -ltr
```

i.e. you grep e.g. "hello world" in *.txt, with -sil you make the grep case insensitive (-i), suppress messages (-s) and just list files (-l); this you then pass on to ls (| xargs), sorting it by date (-t) showing date (-l) and all files (-a).